# Why isn't Meta Stack Exchange available on Careers?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs, mso-mse-split

Before the grand split, I had Meta Stack Overflow on my Careers profile since I felt like I showed that I took the time to understand the community and add value. After the split I assumed Meta Stack Exchange would be shown in it's place. But currently, Meta Stack Exchange isn't displayed on my profile, and isn't an option to be displayed.

I understand why child-meta sites (like Meta Stack Overflow) aren't available to be displayed. But is there a reason that Meta Stack Exchange isn't available?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I saw that too; I'd consider it a bug.

Comment: It shows up an as an option for me - I'll take a look and see if there's any reason it might not be appearing for you guys, as you clearly have enough rep on MSE for it to show up in the list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was able to sync yours up manually as part of troubleshooting, but we're still looking for an overall solution. Everybody else please bear with us...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a regular job which runs to sync your Stack Exchange accounts with your Careers profile. Most people's accounts update regularly, so most people could link their MSE account to their Careers profile.

However, some accounts were kind of getting stuck in a time warp and hadn't updated since early April, which meant that the new MSE profile wasn't showing up.

I've fixed this now - when syncing Stack Exchange accounts, we now prioritise those which are most stale (i.e. which haven't synced for the longest). This means no more time warps and everybody's stats should be reasonably up-to-date.