# why is my careers profile reputation lower than my actual repuation?

Tags: bug, reputation, jobs

When I look at my reputation on stackoverflow I see one number, but when I look at my profile in the careers.stackoverflow I see another number.

Is it just slow to update (maybe it's a few days behind...)?

UPDATE:  Looks like this problem has been solved.  As of 5-28-14 my reputation levels in stackoverflow and careers.stackoverflow are now consistent.  Thanks to those doing the fixing!

Comment: It's more than a week behind for me. It also says "Last seen on May 4," even though I've visited every day since then.

Comment: Looks like whatever internal job that is responsible to synchronize those details (reputation and last seen) crashed in May 4th and never came back.

Comment: Bueller?  Bueller?  Bueller?  This _still_ has not been rectified - or happened again?  [My Careers 2.0 profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/j0e3gan) shows that my SO reputation is 3,051 points and I last visited SO on May 5; but [my SO profile](http://http://stackoverflow.com/users/1810429/j0e3gan) shows that my reputation is 3,494 and I last visited 18 minutes ago.

Comment: Still happening, Careers hasn't updated last time seen nor the reputation counters.

Comment: Same here. No reason to panic, but no reason to assume it's fixed either.

Comment: I've summoned the cavalry, hope to see them charging on that bug. :)

Comment: Mine has been updated again :).

Comment: @NickLarsen, it seems to be fixed now, however, at the time it was a new instance of the same bug that was fixed in the past (and the older question was marked as completed and closed). In that case are we supposed to vote to reopen the old question or create a new question as done here?

Comment: @NickLarsen, this is not the first duplicate (see the question I previous linked to here) and that one was reopened due to the return of the bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225383/my-stack-overflow-reputation-is-not-getting-update-on-careers-site?lq=1