# UX reputation out of date on Careers, all others in sync

Tags: support, bug, jobs

My Careers 2.0 profile has up-to-date (within a few days) reputation information for all of the Stack Exchange sites *except* for User Experience (UX), which still shows me at 101 reputation. I have been actively participating in UX questions for over two weeks, and have yet to see any changes to the reputation score on my Careers profile, let alone an up-to-date score.

Careers profile: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/martincarney

UX Stack Exchange profile: https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/11138/mouseas

Answer (score 1):

Took care of that for you.  For reference, it updates on a loop that refreshes your profile about twice a day, so it's not real time, but it's never that far out of date.

Comment: Not sure about that Nick. I have a similar problem too. My UX.SE reputation isn't updating on my profile either. The UX rep total in my profile isn't in sync. In fact it hasn't even been that number since about May 17th-18th.

Comment: Yeah, it was my understanding that they update pretty regularly.

Comment: Another report, I'll look into it.

Comment: I strongly believe it's the same bug as [reported here two weeks ago already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231596/why-is-my-careers-profile-reputation-lower-than-my-actual-repuation). (which never got any official attention)